# Server specification

Tags: server, hosting

I'd like to know server specifications for wordpress portal, knowing provided below data:

For user with accounts

Number of accounts 40k  + 1000 per year

Number of user in peek hour  - 16000

avarage requests per session - 350

think time - 7s

For anonim users

Users daily - 6k - 8k

user in peek hour - 600 - 800

avarage requests per session - 10 - 15

think time - 7s

I've been researching but I can't find any data how should I calculate this ... Can anyone help with this one ?

Comment: There is no reliable method to do this. The factors you've given is just a small percentage that will determine the outcome. You are overlooking some very important stuff here which can have a huge influence on your calculations. You have to consider site content, themes, plugins, db queries, queries, and the list go on and on. If decide to go big, you must be able to pay up for proper hosting with proper hosts, these mickey mouse hosts will just frustrate you

Comment: I'm gonna have my own hosting, thats why I'd like to know which are the minimum and maximum requirements.

Comment: Then your question is definitely not suited for this stack. You should try webmasters stack then.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Peter's comment, it is very much depending on the technology you use which in turn might depend on the software architecture.

If you can create a condition in which you can serve cached pages 99% of the time (by using caching plugins or varnish in front of your site) then you will  be able to actually handle a lot of traffic with a single server of 8 or 16 GB of memory, but if every request requires access to a db then you might need same size of server just for the DB itself.

So basically, unless you just have a lot of money that you want to spend, you ask the wrong question and instead of looking for a server that will fit the requirements you should ask yourself how can you optimize your site in a way that will make it consume less resources.